# Laravel 5.5 Service Provider

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am trying to have a custom service provider with common methods that I am using throughout my application. However I am getting an error target not instantiable. I have the same working fine in Laravel 5.3 but now its not working in Laravel 5.5. Here is my code:
In the app\Helpers folder, I have created a folder Contracts with an interface FrontendContracts.

```
namespace App\Helpers\Contracts;

Interface FrontendContracts{
    public function randomString($len);
}
```

In app\Helpers I have a class FrontendMethods which implements the interface

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use App\Helpers\Contracts\FrontendContracts;

class FrontendMethods implements FrontendContracts{
public function randomString($len){
        $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz";
        $result = "";
        $charArray = str_split($chars);
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
            $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
            $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
        }
        $result .= time();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

In the app\Providers I have FrontendServiceProvider class with:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Helpers\FrontendMethods;

class FrontendServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(){
        //
    }
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(){
        $this->app->bind('App\Helpers\Contracts\FrontendContracts', function(){

            return new FrontendMethods();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides(){
        return ['App\Helpers\Contracts\FrontendContracts'];
    }

}
```

I have registered the provider in the providers array as:

```
App\Providers\FrontendServiceProvider::class,
```

I am getting the error message Unresolvable dependency resolving [$parameter] in class {$parameter->getDeclaringClass()->getName()}

and Target [App\Helpers\Contracts\FrontendContracts] is not instantiable.

Can someone kindly point at to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `provides()` method in your `FrontendServiceProvider` class. Try removing this.